# tsc is using global @types instead of local

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsc

I recently started getting compilation errors on my project.

```
➜  test-plugin git:(main) yarn run tsc
yarn run v1.22.18
$ /Users/myUsername/workspace/Project/node_modules/.bin/tsc
src/component.tsx:70:6 - error TS2786: 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/buda/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props

70     <View
        ~~~~
```

Looks like the problem is caused by my typescript compiler is using global types definition `'import("/Users/myUsername/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.`
instead of the ones installed locally. `/Users/myUsername/workspace/Project/node_modules/`

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to force ts to use local nmode_modules for types definitions?

```json
"dependencies": {
   "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
   "@types/react-native": "0.62.2",
   "react-native": "0.62.2",
   "typescript": "4.3.2"
},
```

Here is my ts configuration:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

base.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib", "**/__tests__", "manifests"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding typeRoots key to tsconfig pointing to local `node_modules` fixes the issues.

```json
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
```

Looks like the typescript compiler is favouring globally installed types rather than locally.